# How do I install opencv3 with VTK features using homebrew?

Tags: opencv, homebrew, opencv3.0

I have already installed opencv3 using brew, however the installation doesn't have the viz binary and headers.

My question is, how can I upgrade my installation to include VTK features? In particular I would like the Viz module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install VTK (6.3.0) before opencv3.

```
brew install vtk
```

then

```
brew install opencv3 --verbose
```

In the installation log output, check that configure finds VTK and adds support to it.

```
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.0.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Darwin 15.0.0 x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.3.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/gmake
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES


...


-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     Cocoa:                       YES
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 YES (ver 6.3.0)
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/libz.dylib (ver 1.2.5)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.dylib (ver 80)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
--     PNG:                         /usr/local/lib/libpng.dylib (ver 1.6.18)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/local/lib/libtiff.dylib (ver 42 - 4.0.6)
--     JPEG 2000:                   NO
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lo
```

Comment: You had me until "and check that configure finds VTK and adds support to it.". Could you elaborate on how I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Ignore my last comment. I understand now.

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but brew simply downloads the prebuilt opencv3 version, unzips it and declares success. I didn't see the output that you reference above (note I had a previous installation that I `brew uninstall`ed.